# java apis for remote git repository access

Tags: git, svn, svnkit

Is there any java api available that can be used to access version history of a remote git repository when url is provided. I am looking for something equivalent to svnkit. I have looked into javagit but it seems it does not have a option for remote access. Any help would be great!

Comment: same requirement here. i want to to monitor the linux kernel commit log message remotely (don't want to clone the whole repository, only need the commit log message), and post it to IRC channel if there're new commits.

Answer (score 1):

git repository is always local, by design.

So, unless you can use something like `gitweb`, `cgit` or `ssh` which can deliver that information for you over the network, this is not possible.

It would have been possible if you were able to access git key-value object store remotely, but git simply prefers to copy whole object store first, and then look at it locally.